# What should the target variable (y) look like here?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cross-validation, mean

I am doing some data science problems for practice, and this is the question I'm currently tackling:

Given a list of L values generated independently by some unknown process, we will use the mean of L to predict unseen values generated by the same process. Use leave-one-out cross-validation to estimate the mean absolute error (MAE) of this process.

- Input: An array of floats arr
- Output: A float score

Example:

- arr = [1,2,3],
- score = 1.0

Now, usually, the input variables (X) and target variable (y) have the same number of rows. But in this case, since it says "we will use the mean of L to predict unseen values", what does y look like? Because in the given example, X has just one column, so if we take the mean of X, we will get a scalar value, which gives error when trying to do cross-validation:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut, cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

# input list of values
x = [[2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9]]

# define the output as the mean of the inputs, as specified in the question
y = [np.mean(x)]

# build multiple linear regression model
model = LinearRegression()

# define cross-validation method to use
cv = LeaveOneOut()

# use LOOCV to evaluate model
scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)

# view mean absolute error
np.mean(np.absolute(scores))

>>> 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:862, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    861 try:
--> 862     tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    863 except queue.Empty:
    864     # slice the iterator n_jobs * batchsize items at a time. If the
    865     # slice returns less than that, then the current batchsize puts
   (...)
    868     # accordingly to distribute evenly the last items between all
    869     # workers.

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/queue.py:168, in Queue.get(self, block, timeout)
    167     if not self._qsize():
--> 168         raise Empty
    169 elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [70], in <cell line: 18>()
     15 cv = LeaveOneOut()
     17 # use LOOCV to evaluate model
---> 18 scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
     20 # view mean absolute error
     21 np.mean(np.absolute(scores))

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:515, in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    512 # To ensure multimetric format is not supported
    513 scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
--> 515 cv_results = cross_validate(
    516     estimator=estimator,
    517     X=X,
    518     y=y,
    519     groups=groups,
    520     scoring={"score": scorer},
    521     cv=cv,
    522     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    523     verbose=verbose,
    524     fit_params=fit_params,
    525     pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
    526     error_score=error_score,
    527 )
    528 return cv_results["test_score"]

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:266, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    263 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    264 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    268         clone(estimator),
    269         X,
    270         y,
    271         scorers,
    272         train,
    273         test,
    274         verbose,
    275         None,
    276         fit_params,
    277         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    278         return_times=True,
    279         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    280         error_score=error_score,
    281     )
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
    285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1085, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1076 try:
   1077     # Only set self._iterating to True if at least a batch
   1078     # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
   (...)
   1082     # was very quick and its callback already dispatched all the
   1083     # remaining jobs.
   1084     self._iterating = False
-> 1085     if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1086         self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1088     while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:873, in Parallel.dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    870 n_jobs = self._cached_effective_n_jobs
    871 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
--> 873 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    874 if len(islice) == 0:
    875     return False

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:266, in <genexpr>(.0)
    263 # We clone the estimator to make sure that all the folds are
    264 # independent, and that it is pickle-able.
    265 parallel = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose, pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
--> 266 results = parallel(
    267     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    268         clone(estimator),
    269         X,
    270         y,
    271         scorers,
    272         train,
    273         test,
    274         verbose,
    275         None,
    276         fit_params,
    277         return_train_score=return_train_score,
    278         return_times=True,
    279         return_estimator=return_estimator,
    280         error_score=error_score,
    281     )
    282     for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups)
    283 )
    285 _warn_or_raise_about_fit_failures(results, error_score)
    287 # For callabe scoring, the return type is only know after calling. If the
    288 # return type is a dictionary, the error scores can now be inserted with
    289 # the correct key.

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:86, in BaseCrossValidator.split(self, X, y, groups)
     84 X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
     85 indices = np.arange(_num_samples(X))
---> 86 for test_index in self._iter_test_masks(X, y, groups):
     87     train_index = indices[np.logical_not(test_index)]
     88     test_index = indices[test_index]

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:98, in BaseCrossValidator._iter_test_masks(self, X, y, groups)
     93 def _iter_test_masks(self, X=None, y=None, groups=None):
     94     """Generates boolean masks corresponding to test sets.
     95 
     96     By default, delegates to _iter_test_indices(X, y, groups)
     97     """
---> 98     for test_index in self._iter_test_indices(X, y, groups):
     99         test_mask = np.zeros(_num_samples(X), dtype=bool)
    100         test_mask[test_index] = True

File ~/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:163, in LeaveOneOut._iter_test_indices(self, X, y, groups)
    161 n_samples = _num_samples(X)
    162 if n_samples <= 1:
--> 163     raise ValueError(
    164         "Cannot perform LeaveOneOut with n_samples={}.".format(n_samples)
    165     )
    166 return range(n_samples)

ValueError: Cannot perform LeaveOneOut with n_samples=1.
```

---

Curiously, if I duplicate the contents of X and y, the error goes away, and a `score` of `0.0` is outputted:

```
# input list of values
x = [[2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9], [2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9]]

# define the output as the mean of the inputs, as specified in the question
y = [np.mean(x),np.mean(x)]
...
...
...

>>> 0.0
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not interpreted the problem correctly.

I will try to explain using your example, with the array `[1, 2, 3]`.

Because there are only 3 samples, the cross validation is called "leave one out".

First fold, elements `[1, 2]` are used for training and `[3]` for testing.
The mean of the train elements is 1.5, so the prediction is 1.5, so the absolute error is 3-1.5 = 1.5.

Similarly we repeat by choosing `2` and `1` as the test elements and the other two as train.

Mean of 1 and 3: 2,   absolute error = 2-2 = 0
Mean of 2 and 3: 2.5, absolute error = |1 - 2.5| = 1.5

So, the mean absolute error will be `mean([1.5, 0, 1.5]) = 1.0`.

You tried to think about the problem as a usual machine learning problem with tabular data, but essentially your X is not a row (the problem statement mentions that the input is an array, but you define it as a 2D array in the code), it is a column which happens to be both your feature, and the target variable, and the model you have to use is simply `y_pred = np.mean(x)`.

The following snippet does not use library functions (well, apart from `np.mean`) and is easy to understand:

```
import numpy as np

def model(X):
  return np.mean(X)
  
def cross_validation(X, model):
    errors = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        test_element = X[i]
        train_elements = X[0:i] + X[i+1:len(X)]
        
        prediction = model(train_elements)
        error = abs(prediction - test_element)
        errors.append(error)
        
    return np.mean(errors)
        
        
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [2, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 7, 5, 8, 9]
print(cross_validation(arr1, model))
print(cross_validation(arr2, model))
```

and produces

```
1.0
1.9555555555555557
```